# Redshift - Case insensitive grouping

Tags: grouping, amazon-redshift, case-insensitive

Is there a way to make 'group by' in redshift case insensitive. I have contents in a table which have values like below. I'm trying to figure out a way to make the following 2 fields get grouped as one.

Pricewaterhousecoopers LLP
PricewaterhouseCoopers LLP

Thanks

Comment: hi, perhaps group by a `lower()` expression

Answer (score 0):

You could group using the `LOWER` function, e.g.

```sql
SELECT LOWER(company) AS company, SUM(sales) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LOWER(company);
```

Comment: Just remember that if the column in question is the DISTKEY and the table is very large there could be significant slow down with lower().  You may want to group by the raw column and then on the lower() of the column.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a easy way to identify all the names which are exactly same except for case sensitive differences ? I'm not able to do group in excel as it is case insensitive

Comment: What would the output look like from this follow-up question?  I'm not sure exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I was able to identify the names like so -
select  name, LOWER(name) as lc_name into #tmp1 from sales
select name from #tmp1 where lc_name in (select lc_name from #tmp1 group by lc_name having count(name) > 1)